# Returning the most recent messages from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to add a join to the following query that will join the messages_message table to the messages_threads table and return the 'body' and 'time' fields from the most recent row in messages_messages where messages_message.threadid = messages_threads.id.

Sorry that's so confusing, I don't know how else to phrase it!  Here's my current query - which pulls everything correctly except the 'body' and 'time' fields.

```
SELECT 
    messages_threads.id AS threadid, messages_threads.name AS recipientsname, 
    senderid, username AS sendername, pictures.url AS senderpicture
FROM 
    messages_recipients
    JOIN messages_threads 
        ON messages_threads.id = messages_recipients.threadid
    JOIN users 
        ON users.id = messages_threads.senderid
    JOIN pictures 
        ON messages_threads.senderid = pictures.userid 
        AND pictures.profile = 1
WHERE messages_recipients.userid = $userid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a subquery of the messages_message table which would return 1 row for every thread.  For example:

```
SELECT 
    messages_threads.id AS threadid, messages_threads.name AS recipientsname, 
    senderid, username AS sendername, pictures.url AS senderpicture
FROM 
    messages_recipients
    JOIN messages_threads ON messages_threads.id = messages_recipients.threadid
    JOIN users ON users.id = messages_threads.senderid
    JOIN pictures ON messages_threads.senderid = pictures.userid AND pictures.profile = 1
    JOIN ( SELECT threadid, MAX(id) AS postid FROM messages_message GROUP BY threadid ) t ON message_threads.id = t.threadid
    JOIN messages_message ON t.threadid = messages_message.threadid AND t.postid = messages_message.id
WHERE messages_recipients.userid = $userid
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need Group by body and time also...
 or can u more specify your query..

Comment: Hi, I haven't added the join to messages_messages yet - I'm trying to decide how.  Are you suggesting a subquery with group by?

Comment: If you know that in the message_thread table field count or examine so gruop by is needed. otherwise there is alot of simple solution.

Comment: Juddas answer worked, do you have a simpler solution?  Thanks for helping!

Comment: i think judda answer is suitable.